# Object Oriented design interview Q

Tags: oop

When companies ask you to do OO design related questions in the interview, what do they really expect? Do they expect you to briefly tell them the algorithm and some pseudocode or do they actually expect you to write the entire structure of the code?

For example question like : Design a musical jukebox. Do I start off telling what classes I will make with some pseudocode or what?

Comment: Why not ask them? They know what kind of answer they're looking for, and they don't usually mind telling you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design does not mean implementation.
Design means:

- what all classes you will have
- The methods(functionality) your classes will provide
- What will be the relation between classes you have
- What will be the Lifetimes of objects of your classed

Having said a design is not something which gets done in a mere 15-20mins of an interview.It's all blood and sweat and it needs lot of time and consideration albeit discussions to arrive at a good design.
In a interview the Questioner usually want to know if you can think in the right direction atleast.